# how to update a parameter (at each epoch based on the input state of that epoch) within a keras custom layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, layer

I have a keras sequential model and there i have a custom layer for expample lets say its name is 'LayerX'.
Now in 'LayerX' i have a parameter 'lambda' which i want to initialize with a value for example lambda = 10,

Now, at the time of training, at each epoch, i take the input in the 'call' method of that 'LayerX' layer and i calculate a value suppose 'valX' based on the inputs at that epoch and i want to update parameter 'lamba' at each epoch with this value 'valX'. Suppose, at each epoch, lambda = lambda + valX.

I am new with customization of keras layer. Can anyone help me to get some idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I was extracting the gradients after every epoch. You can make the changes to the model.fit loop to make your custom changes for the layer.

**Note:** I was using tensorflow 1.15.0

```
# (1) Importing dependency
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1000)

# (2) Get Data
import tflearn.datasets.oxflower17 as oxflower17
x, y = oxflower17.load_data(one_hot=True)

# (3) Create a sequential model
model = Sequential()

# 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(224,224,3), kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
# Batch Normalisation before passing it to the next layer
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Passing it to a dense layer
model.add(Flatten())
# 1st Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(224*224*3,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 2nd Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 3rd Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(17))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()

# (4) Compile 
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# (5) Define Gradient Function
def get_gradient_func(model):
    grads = K.gradients(model.total_loss, model.trainable_weights)
    inputs = model.model._feed_inputs + model.model._feed_targets + model.model._feed_sample_weights
    func = K.function(inputs, grads)
    return func

# (6) Train the model such that gradients are captured for every epoch
epoch_gradient = []
for epoch in range(1,5):
    model.fit(x, y, batch_size=64, epochs= epoch, initial_epoch = (epoch-1), verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
    get_gradient = get_gradient_func(model)
    grads = get_gradient([x, y, np.ones(len(y))])
    # Similarly define your function to play with your model.layers,model.layers[].get_weights(),model.input,model.total_loss,model.trainable_weights etc
    # print("Layer of the model:",model.layers[2])
    # print("Weights of the Layer",model.layers[2].get_weights())
    # print(model.input)
    # print(model.total_loss)
    # print(model.trainable_weights)
    epoch_gradient.append(grads)

# (7) Convert to a 2 dimensiaonal array of (epoch, gradients) type
gradient = np.asarray(epoch_gradient)
print("Total number of epochs run:", epoch)
print("Gradient Array has the shape:",gradient.shape)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but my situation is more like within a custom layer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41710515/10645817 this answer gives some insight, but i am not sure whether add_update method works in eager execution or not, currently this is not working for me